# Convert Uint8Array response to file in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, pdf, next.js

Using an API call that returns a `Response<Uint8Array>`, I'm trying to convert the binary data into a PDF that can be downloaded in a React component.

Using Next.js 13.2's API route handlers, the PDF is generated like this:

```js
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const binaryResponse = await client.renderPdf(templateId, data);

  // Just to test, this works. The PDF can be written successfully from the backend
  // const writeFileAsync = promisify(fs.writeFile);
  // await writeFileAsync("file.pdf", Buffer.from(binaryResponse.data))

  return NextResponse.json(binaryResponse);
}
```

Then in the React component, the response is handled like this

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/pdf', { method: 'post' });
if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error('Failed to generate PDF');
}

const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: 'application/pdf' });

// Also tried this 
// const blob = await response.blob();
// const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
```

The resulting file that is downloaded is corrupt. If I pull it into a plain text editor, the PDF just contains the raw binary response instead of the rendered content.

```
{"data":{"0":37,"1":80,"2":68,"3":70,"4":45,"5":49,"6":46,"7":51,"8":10,"9":37,..."status":200}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: If I generate the PDF directly from the component, it works

```js
const binaryResponse = await client.renderPdf(tenmplateId, values);
const blob = new Blob([binaryResponse.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
```

which makes me think the issue is in the response from the API call, or how it's handled.